# (Python, Selenium) Is it possible to get text list only if the attribute meets criteria?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

Not sure I made my point in the title.

Let's the sorce code first.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label>
          Want to
          Get these texts
          only if img exist
        </label>
        <img src="Some td tags don't contain img" alt="alt"></img>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <label>
          Want to
          Get these texts
          only if img exist
        </label>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
...
...
...
</tbody>
```

As it's saying up there, there are lots of (about 1,000) sets of  tags. And inside of those, sometimes  tags with certain alt value exist(which are all same) while sometimes don't (just like the second part.)

So what I'm trying to do is to get label text only if it has  tag as its sibling. So far, no good.

Anybody's help will be appreciated!

(P.S. I just got into python world, so a little more description will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!)

Comment: Show what you've tried already

Comment: You can use selenium to `find_elements_...` to find all of the `<p>` elements, then in each of those elements you can `find_elements_...` to get subelements, and check if there's an `img` in each, if there is, store the `label`

Comment: Well what I tried is most stupidest thing... (like... get source code and analyze it as a whole text thing...)...(too shame to say)

Comment: Wow, Thank you for the fast help! I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below to get list of required text values

```
labels = [label.text for label in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[following-sibling::img[@alt="alt"]]')]
```

Comment: Oh My God ! ! ! ! !
It perfectly worked! I still can't believe someone can solve the problem while I'm stuck for hours!! I should learn it much more,
And just learnt more! Thank you Andersson!
(I'm sooooo happy right now.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Xpath.

This will return only label which has image. Here we find the label which is preceding sibiling to image.

```
labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody//../img/preceding-sibling::label")
```

Comment: Thanks for stop by Navarasu! So I can use both following and preceding too. Is there any difference?